# Rollback changes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I don't know about MSSQL , i have two site one is php and another site is cold fusion ,

My php site using mysql , my cold fusion using the MSSQL ,

my old site is the cold fusion still we are using cold fusion and , becoz it is old site

lot of records in sql, still we are moved to mysql ,

Now what happen suddenly ,

couple of days back , site admin ,

for migration purpose (SQL TO MYSQL) , for full access reason , by mistake, instead of

giving full permission level to juniors, by mistake site super admin deleted the all users ,

So that users related records are suffled to super admin ,

now i want to do all revert ,

What should i do now,

Any ideas ? corruption done on MSSQL  ,

This are happened couple of days back,

Now i want revert all change ,

Any suggestions ,

Thanks for edited ,

My SQL server version is 2005

Comment: Don't get me wrong, and as always no insult intended...but is your period/dot-key broken?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you can do a:

```
 RESTORE DATABASE { database_name | @database_name_var }  [ FROM <backup_device> [ ,...n ] ]
```

Basicly: [put back a backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What version is the MSSQL server(2000, 2005, 2008) ? If it is SQL 2000, then you can try out [SQL Log Rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Log_Rescue/index.htm) from red-gate.

All the best.

Comment: If you have backup then take up the advice of @GvS and restore them to a separate DB. Then you can move only the needed values from the needed tables. If not then your other option would be to use Apex SQL Log Recovery from http://sqldbpool.com/2008/04/16/how-to-read-transaction-log-data-in-sql-server-20002005/